# Why does plt.hlines() adjust ylims when used with transform, but plt.plot() does not?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to display a horizontal line at 20% of the y-axis using [`plt.hlines()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) with `y=[0.2]` and the `transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform()` argument. When I do this the  upper ylim of my plot is changed to 0.2 automatically.

I do not expect this behaviour because to my understanding the [`get_xaxis_transform()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis_transform.html?highlight=xaxis_transform#matplotlib-axes-axes-get-xaxis-transform)-transform should transform the `y=[0.2]` value to whatever corresponds to 20% of my y-axis. In particular because the hline *is* displayed at 20% but the limits are adjusted anyways.

This does *not* happen when I perform the same operation using [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) (rightmost plot). Here, the line stays at 20% of the y-axis even when interactively moving the visible area.

I am wondering why this happens and how I can avoid that `hlines()` adjusts the ylims when using it with the transform parameter.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.rand(20)/100  # scale so all values should be far below 0.2
x = range(len(y))

# Scenario 0 (auto-scaled axes)
fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax0.set(title='No horizontal lines drawn')

# Scenario 1
ax1.hlines(y=[0.2], xmin=5, xmax=15, transform=ax1.get_xaxis_transform(), color='black')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set(title='Using hlines()')

# Scenario 2
ax2.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot([5, 15], [0.2, 0.2], transform=ax2.get_xaxis_transform(), color='black')
ax2.set(title='Using plot()')

plt.show(block=True)
```

[image: 3 plots, leftmost does not use hlines() nor plot() to show horizontal line, middle one uses hlines() and adjusts y-axis automatically, rightmost one uses plot() and does not adjust ylim]

Comment: So, you want a line with fixed location in terms of data, is that it?

Comment: The line should always be at 20% height of the y-axis, so it shouldn't move in height when I move the visible area. But it should always be between 5-15 on the x-axis, so it kind of indicates the data range between x=5 to x=15.
For both methods it works to have the line at 20%, but in the `hlines()` case also the ylims are adjusted automatically, which I do not want. So basically I want the plot in the middle to look and behave the same as the plot on the right (which I could do of course by manually adjusting the ylims, but that shouldn't be necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of a bug in matplotlib.
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23171

As you've discovered, using [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) is a simple workaround.